# Why is my .htaccess redirect not working?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect incoming requests for old pdfs that do not exist in the server anymore. This is what I've put in my .htaccess but it's not working. It always takes me to the custom 404 error page. What have I done wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^files\/2002\/pdfs\/Home\%20Doc\.pdf$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/docs\/" [R=301,L]
```

Here `files/2002/pdfs/Home Doc.pdf` is an old file that does not exist in the website anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange your rules to keep 301 redirect before silent rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule "^files/2002/pdfs/Home Doc\.pdf$" http://mydomain.com/docs/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like there are issues with the spaces in the pdf file `%20`. I tried with files without images and they work fine. Is there a way to represent spaces in a different way in .htaccess?

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work for me: `RewriteRule "files/2002/pdfs/Home Doc.pdf" docs/ [R=301,L]` I haven't tried yours though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes both versions will work fine, I have update answer with your version but with escaped dot.